# Syntax: a little more romance

Tags: syntax

I'm not sure if "more" in this sentence role as a determiner or an adverb.

> What you need is a little more romance. [[1]](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/little-a-little-few-a-few?q=Little%2C%20a%20little%2C%20few%2C%20a%20few)

Is it qualifying "is" or "romance"?

I perceive that it performs the function of an adverb, Which in turn precedes another adverb (little), *but I'm not sure.*

Comment: Why don't you think it's an adjective?

Comment: It is an adjective? haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "*romance*" here is used as a noun.

The word "*more*" is thuis ab adjective (not an adverb) modifying "romance".

The word "*little*" here is an adverb modifying "more". Alternatively one could consider "*little more*" to be a compound adjective, modifying "romance".

But "more" is not an adverb here, nor is it a [determiner](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/determiner) because it is not:

> a word which is used at the beginning of a noun group to indicate, for example, which thing you are referring to or whether you are referring to one thing or several.

The noun phrase here is "*a little more romance*" and the determiner is "a".

Comment: You saved my night, David. Thank you a lot. Have a nice week!